# Rails ZeroClipBoard Copy to clipboard not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, clipboard, zeroclipboard

In my rails app I want to use `ZeroClipboard` to copy a text in the clipboard.
There is my code :

```
 var clip = new ZeroClipboard($('#copy-clipboard'), {
    moviePath: "/ZeroClipboard.swf",
  });

  $('#copy-clipboard').click(function() {
    // #copy-clipboard -> is the button
    // $(this).data('clipboard-text') -> contains the text to cpy   
    clip.setText($(this).data('clipboard-text'));

  });
```

I tried to also use that way : `moviePath: "http://localhost:3000/ZeroClipboard.swf",`

But same result, nothing is copied.

Any ideas ?
Ty

Comment: look @ browser console for any errors

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: `ZeroClipboard.swf` located? do try `/ZeroClipboard.swf` and `../ZeroClipboard.swf`

Comment: already `/ZeroClipboard.swf`,  tried `../ZeroClipboard.swf`  no change

Comment: is `swf` loaded to your page? look up through `view page source`

Comment: I can take it at `localhost:3000/ZeroClipboard.swf` if you think about that

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume that you use ID to tag?

```
 jQuery.fn.copyToClipBoard = function() {
      var clip = new ZeroClipboard($('#copy-clipboard'));
  }
  $(function() {
    $('#copy-clipboard').copyToClipBoard();
  });
```

By using this parameter you define the function as a jQuery function. For example you can use this method with button (in the view):

```
 <button class='btn btn-success'  id='copy-clipboard'  data-clipboard-text= "http://localhost:3000/ZeroClipboard.swf"> <p> Click me to Copy </p>
```

I hope this help you in some way